# How can I prevent the network from slowing down while pinging IP's from a SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my Web Forms app I have a database with the IP addresses of various device on my network.
When the application runs it then pings those IP and display's either a green tick for success, a yellow exclamation mark for slow response and a red error icon for `NoReply` or `DestinationHostUnreachable`

I also have a `Panel` displaying only the devices with a slow ping response or timedout.

All of this work great but what I have noticed over a day or two the network slows down completely - bear in mind that it is pinging 50+ IP addresses continuously.

I need to find a way to make the pinging of the IP address efficient so not to slow down the network.

This is my code I am currently using:

```
  private void NetworkDevices()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewServer.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Image Image2 = new Image();
                Image Image3 = new Image();
                Image Image4 = new Image();
                Panel serverPanel = (Panel)row.FindControl("ServerPanel");
                string destIP = GridViewServer.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                string destHost = GridViewServer.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Ping p = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply;
                        reply = p.Send(destIP);

                        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            if (reply.RoundtripTime > 50)
                            {
                                Image2.ImageUrl = "../Images/yellow.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image2);
                                Image2.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                                Label dynamicLabel = new Label()
                                {
                                    Text = destHost.ToString() + "  " + Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms") + "<br/>",
                                };
                                Image img = new Image()
                                {
                                    ImageUrl = "../Images/yellow.png",
                                };
                                OverViewUpdate.Controls.Add(img);
                                OverViewUpdate.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel);
                                Panel.Update();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Image3.ImageUrl = "../Images/green.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image3);
                                Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                            serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                            Label dynamicLabel = new Label()
                            {
                                Text = destHost.ToString() + "  " + reply.Status.ToString() + "<br/>",
                            };
                            Image img = new Image()
                            {
                                ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png",
                            };
                            OverViewUpdate.Controls.Add(img);
                            OverViewUpdate.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel);
                            Panel.Update();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                        serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: So you're basically ping flooding your own network?  I think the solution is to ping less often.  And quite honestly, you won't lose any useful information in doing so either.

Comment: @Duston So basically running it as a background / Async task with flood the network too?  There are devices I need to check continuously (frequently) so that I can be proactive and get the device back online if they go down.

Comment: How frequently is "frequently"?  Once per minute? Once per second?  Ten times per second?  Thousands of times per second?

Comment: it pings the list of IP's every 10 seconds

Comment: I would increase that - say to 50 seconds  - see if that helps.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thanks, I have increased the time to 50 seconds to test.  I have also added `(p as IDisposable).Dispose();` --> not sure if this will make much of an impact, but worth a try :-)